# Setting the file extension of a file being downloaded by DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm downloading a file from a url but I don't know the file type until the download begins. I can obtain the mimetype from the server using `DownloadManager` by inspecting `COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE` when the download starts.

Is it possible to change the destination uri so it includes the file extension on the fly whilst it is downloading to take into account the file type? Currently, when the download finishes, I rename the file after the fact, but this leads to a lot of broken links (both in the download manager app and in the gallery).

Comment: Why do you need to set the extention?  Linux (and Android) don't really use them as part of the OS.  So it doesn't need to be there, or need to be accurate.  Besides, don't you get the full filename of the file as part of the URI?  Can't you just parse that?

Comment: I need to be able to associate the file with a mimetype so I can create an `Intent` and set the data & type values correctly. Whilst newer versions of android can cope with missing type values, older versions will not and will simply not open the file unless you specify the kind of file. I would think that using file extensions would be neater than trying to keep the file location and mimetype paired together. Whilst I appreciate that extensions aren't used much, they ARE necessary, which can easily be seen by removing an extension in a file manager and seeing how it then launches intents.